# Trying to use an INSERT method but not working

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm trying to use an `insert` method in my `studentHelperClass`, I am trying to activate it on a button click on my form, I don't know how to make it work with a text box, so if someone could help with that, that would be great.

This is my method:

```
public static void insertStudent()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = connection();
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personID) ";
            cmd.Prepare();
            myInsertSQL += "VALUES (@personID)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", "123345667788");
            prevID(conn, cmd);
        }
```

and this is my form:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                     studentHelperClass.insertStudent();
                 }
```

EDIT:

```
private static void prevID(MySqlConnection conn, MySqlCommand cmd)
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long studentNumber = (long)cmd.LastInsertedId;
            Console.Write("previous id {0} ", studentNumber);
            Console.ReadLine();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: So your form calls a method to delete a student, but your method inserts one.

Comment: oops sorry, that's my bad I made a typo when posting the code. Edited above

Comment: What do you mean by "making it work with a textbox"? Do you have a student id in a textbox that you want to use? Or do you want to call the method on some textbox event?

Comment: by text box I mean instead of telling it `123345667788` to put that in, I would like to tell it to accept what I type into a text box that is on the form instead

Comment: please show your prevID() method

Comment: So if you want to insert text box value then get the text  box value into string variable by using `YourTexbox.Text` property and then pass that variable to the `AddWithValue` method

Comment: If this is really your code, you should get an exception at `conn.open()` inside the `prevID()`method, as you pass a allready opened connection.

Comment: hmm, it is my code, and I dont get that exception, :/

Comment: ok so i removed `conn.open();` in the `previd` and now if i click insert with a value in the textbox it crashes and points to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: `crashes and points to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and what is the exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the information, assuming that your prevId(conn,cmd) is calling ExecuteNonQuery, you will still need to set the cmd.CommandText to be equal to your myInsertSql (as other answers have pointed out).

To answer your question though,

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    studentHelperClass.insertStudent(studentIdTextBox.Text);
}

public static void insertStudent(string studentId)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = connection();
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personID) ";
    cmd.Prepare();
    myInsertSQL += "VALUES (?personID)";
    cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQL;        
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?personID", studentId);
    prevID(conn, cmd);
}
```

Ive also assumed your studentId is a string. If the database has it as a bigint, you will have to do the proper `long.TryParse()` call.

Comment: hmmm, still no errors with the code, but still doesnt insert... :/

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the order of cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQL

Comment: @MelvinDVaz, you also need to replace `@` with `?` as MySQL uses the questionmark instead of the ad sign as a paremeter prefix.

Comment: Oh okay. I myself haven't used MySqlConnection object so I just copied what was there. Although I think it works since apparently older MySql providers used the @ symbol, and there is an option to allow it in the new providers. I will update my answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `cmd.CommandText` as `myInsertSQL`

and also need to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES (@personID)";
using (MySqlConnection conn = connection())
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ` prevID(conn, cmd);` is calling a method below that has the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: But you don't use in the parameter of prevID the sqlString so this method does not know what command to execute

Comment: Ok, using the above code I get no errors, but it does not insert the new id `123345667788`

Comment: @user2767155 what is the id column type in database?

Comment: the personID in the DB is an int an PK. I have tried it with firstName which is string and not a PK

Comment: Don't you have more columns that are not null in the database?

Comment: @user2767155 if it is int try with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", 123345667);` without quotes

Answer (score 0):

You must assign your string variable, 'myInsertSQL' to cmd.CommandText, and then call, `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

I.e.

```
cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQL;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Always call 'Dispose();' when finished so the .net Garbage Collection can cleanup and manage resources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the myInsertSQL string at all, you just set it. You have to set the string as the command text by `cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQL` and you have to call the method `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.